# After Unhold GSM Call, Callkit become a Mute and I cannot hear any sound

Tags: objective-c, callkit

I checked many similar question but NOT any answer...

I am using Callkit and it works fine. but the issue is when the GSM call arrive and my VOIP call Hold the call and then when I click to swap button of Callkit to unHold My call the unHold request send correctly but the issue is the sound become kind of Mute in Callkit and no-one can hear nothing..

```
- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performSetHeldCallAction:(CXSetHeldCallAction *)action {
    if (action.isOnHold) {

        NSLog(@"Call on hold");


    } else {


        [self holdCall:NO];

    }


    [action fulfill];
}



- (void)holdCall:(BOOL)hold {

    NSLog(@"What is current call uuid %@",self.currentCallUUID);

    CXSetHeldCallAction *holdCallAction = [[CXSetHeldCallAction alloc] initWithCallUUID:self.currentCallUUID onHold:hold];
    CXTransaction *transaction = [[CXTransaction alloc] init];
    [transaction addAction:holdCallAction];
    [self requestTransaction:transaction];
}
```

When I call unHold method it goes to kind of unlimited loop ... anyone has the same issue or how I can unhold the Callkit?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Indeed you're generating an infinite loop: in the `- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performSetHeldCallAction:(CXSetHeldCallAction *)action` function, in the case of unhold, you're calling `- (void)holdCall:(BOOL)hold` that in turn will generate another call to `- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performSetHeldCallAction:(CXSetHeldCallAction *)action`, and so on indefinitely.

So, you just have to remove `[self holdCall:NO];` inside `- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performSetHeldCallAction:(CXSetHeldCallAction *)action`

Comment: where should I add the code call not anymore on hold...?